# Script to Update field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-5, csv-import

I have a csv file which containing parent and their children data.Parent has many children association. What I want is if the family_situation/gross_income or both are different for different children I want the last family_situation/gross_income for that parent to be saved into the database. Like in this case below I want family_situation to be "family of three" and gross income to be "16775". What I current have in my parent model is as below. How can I achieve this please help.

parent.rb

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers:true) do |row|
    parent = Parent.find_or_create_by(
        parent_1_firstname: row["parent_1_firstname"],
        parent_1_lastname: row["parent_1_lastname"],
        family_situation: row["family_situation"],
        gross_income: row["gross_income"],
   )

        parent.children.find_or_create_by(
        firstname: row["firstname"],
        gender: row["gender"]

   )
        end
    end
```

parent.csv

```
parent_1_firstname,parent_1_lastname,family_situation,gross_income,childfirstname,childgender
Josh,Wilson,"family of two",13000,Jessica,Female
Josh,Wilson,"family of three",16775,Jamie,Male
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to save only last value for family_situation and gross_income you can just find existing parent and update it:

```
parent = Parent.find_or_initialize_by(
  parent_1_firstname: row["parent_1_firstname"],
  parent_1_lastname: row["parent_1_lastname"]
).tap do |p|     
  p.family_situation = row["family_situation"]
  p.gross_income = row["gross_income"]
  p.save
end
```

Here you're trying to find a parent with particular first&last names. If it exists, it is instantiated, if not - it is builded with given names. After it you're assigning family_situation and gross_income and save the instance.